# How can i plot time and words in the same axis (one dimension)?

Tags: python, data-science, data-visualization

community,
I have two columns in a csv file, one column containing words and another column contains the time when the word was pronounced, and I want to plot in the same axis the two of them, I tried things with matplotlib for temporal series but didn't found something useful

[image: words and prononciation]

Comment: What do you want your final graph to look like? Is the picture you included the target? Also, what is your use-case? Also also, timestamped data is usually the other way around - timestamp, value. Finally, have you tried Grafana? That takes timestamped data and gives you lovely graphs.